# How can one characterize NP^SAT?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np

Can you help me understand the class of problems solvable by a nondetermimistic Turing machine with an oracle for SAT running in polynomial time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely this class, being $\text{NP}^\text{NP}$, is by definition equal to $\Sigma_2^p$. In particular, if the Polynomial Hierarchy (PH) does not collapse, then it does not contain $\Pi_2^p$.

Comment: Yes you are obviously right, I actually got confused with another question I meant to ask instead about P^NP.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, NP^SAT = NP^NP, because SAT is complete for NP. I don't know what else can be said about this class (it's not in the [complexity zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo)). See the [wikipedia oracle page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) for more details.

By the way, the above "computer" tag is not very relevant, it should rather be "complexity", or "complexity-theory".

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy

Comment: NP^NP actually is in the complexity zoo under its alternative name Sigma_2^p: https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#sigma2p There are some complete problems given there.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that class NP^NP?